# Restlet timeout

Tags: java, timeout, client, restlet

How does one change the timeout on a **Restlet Client** `get()`?

All I've have been able to find is the obsolete `SetConnectTimeout()`. I tried `context.getParameters().add ( "socketTimeout", "1000" );` with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is done by configuring the client connector (class `org.restlet.Client`):

```
client.context.getParameters().add ( "parameter", "value" );
```

I see **two distinct** contexts and thus two ways to get the client connector.

1. You are running your client calls inside a `org.restlet.Component` container
   In this case, configure the common client connector hosted by the component:

   ```
   Component c = new Component();
   Client client = c.getClients().add(Protocol.HTTP);
   client.getContext().getParameters().add ( "parameter", "value" );
   ```
2. You are not running your client calls inside a `org.restlet.Component` container
   In this case, instantiate manually the client connector and set it to the ClientResource

   ```
   Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);
   client.getContext().getParameters().add ( "parameter", "value" );

   ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://example.com");
   cr.setNext(client);
   ```

To conclude with, the list of available parameters to be set depends on the kind of client connector you are using (internal connector, based on `httpclient`, etc)
You can have a look at this page http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/core/base/connectors/.