# Restlet Client Internal Connector Error (1002)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timeout, restlet

I am using a restlet 2.1 client sever based architecture, my client times out within 1 minute after sending the request. and I get the following exception : 
Internal Connector Error (1002) - The calling thread timed out while waiting for a response to unblock it. 
        at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource$1.invoke(ClientResource.java:1663) 
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getTaskList(Unknown Source)....

My code is as below :

import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(uri); 
MyResource resource= cr.wrap(MyResource .class); 
updateStatus = resource.updateData(Parameter);
```

i also tried this code :

```
Context context = new Context();
        context.getParameters().add("socketTimeout", new String("180000"));
        context.getParameters().add("socketConnectTimeoutMs", new String("180000"));
        context.getParameters().add("idleTimeout", new String("180000"));

        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(context, url);

        TasksResource resource = cr.wrap(TasksResource.class);
```

how should I configure my client resource to avoid timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

The connection timeout for a Restlet client can be configured at the client connector level. If your call is within a component, you can get the client connector from it (class Client), otherwise you need to instantiate it. Configuring timeout can be done through its parameters (method getContext and then getParameters).

Parameters depend on the underlying connectors (HTTP client, ...).

The following links will help you to fix your issue:

- [Restlet HTTP Connection Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417669/restlet-http-connection-pool/28438070#28438070)
- [Restlet timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520847/restlet-timeout)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry